# springseed not working after update

Tags: 13.04

After checking other questions, I've found this error with the newest version of springseed. I have followed other questions/answers but this problems seems to be different.

Here is what I get after running springseed from terminal.

```
/opt/springseed/springseed-bin /opt/springseed/nw: error while loading shared libraries: libudev.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have the newest udev installed, so the error is strange. 
I work on Ubuntu 13.04. 
I have tried to change springseed.desktop as in other posts. No results other than this libudev error.

Comment: I also updated SpringSeed through `sudo apt-get update`, and it stopped working for me as well on Ubuntu 13.04 32 bit.<br/>
But when I restarted/rebooted my machine, I can now start it from the terminal using `/opt/springseed/springseed-bin`. The icon has disappeared though, and also it is not searchable from the unity launcher any more.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install the latest version (1.0.2) from [Springseed website](http://getspringseed.com).